# how to add multiple rows of same types in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

[image]
In the below given example like rejection date it has total 5 rows of same type.
when i tried to create new data block item like issue date(issue date is table column) I'm getting only one row (I want to get 5 rows as shown below.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms does that itself, but you have to add that new item into **that** block. Because, it is

1. block's **Number of records displayed** property
2. item's **Number if items displayed** property

that affect number of "rows" you'll see.

For example, if block's number of records displayed is set to 5 (as it apparently is) and you add a new item to that block and set appropriate canvas, Forms *will* create 5 instances of that item. You can then choose not to display all of them but any number between 0 and 5 (where "0" also means "all of them" (5 in this case)).